# How to run a fuzzy LIKE in BigQuery with a Query Parameter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a python script running a BigQuery query with a `ScalarQueryParameter` to make sure the provided string is safe. However, when I try to use a fuzzy LIKE value- it returns no values, whereas without parameters it does return expected values. Example:

I started with a query like:

```
import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query("""
              SELECT name from `people_table` 
              WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%rob%';""") 
query_job = client.query(query_string, job_config=job_config) 
rows = query_job.result()
```

With a query like this, I get expected results of a few rows where name contains 'rob'.

However I'd like to make this take user input. To make it safe, I've rewritten this using [Paramaterized-Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) like below:

```
query_parameters = [bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("name_param", "STRING", "%rob%")] 
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(query_parameters=query_parameters)
query_job = client.query("""
              SELECT name from `people_table` 
              WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE @name_param;""", job_config=job_config)
```

This query runs without error, however it returns no results. I would expect this query to effectively be the equivalent of the above.

Is it possible to use wildcards around string queries using parameters?

Comment: How are you printing the result? Your code is working when I tested it.

Comment: I've added the .result() call here to show how I would have fetched the results. However I believe I've discovered the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the wildcards around string queries using parameters.
The following is based on the documentation link you sent and a public data set.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT corpus, word
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    WHERE corpus like @corpus
    ORDER BY word_count DESC;
"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("corpus", "STRING", "%romeo%")
    ]
)

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request

for row in query_job:
    print(f'{row.corpus}: {row.word}')
```

If you run the following you should get the results associated with a wildcard search of '%romeo%' as you would expect.  Additionally if you change the parameter to '%romeo' you can see that it will not return rows as the data doesn't have data that matches.

I've looked over your code though and it seems like it should be working.

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check. This caused me to inspect elsewhere, and I've found the problem. It appears elsewhere I was inconsistently applying the SQL LOWER() attribute as well as also the .lower() if my input string. This was leading to my inconsistent results.